# Creating mathematical charts using chart.js jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Have you got any ideas how to create user-interactive line math charts with chart.js library, something like in wolframalpha? I know that i need to calculate x and y to draw chart correctly and range. It should look like [myExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VExZJ.png) I can do line charts with static data, put in a code but need to know how to draw it after user provide function e.g 2x+5. All ideas and tricks will be very useful :) Thanks

Comment: Chart js uses a json object, like you said you can do it statically, so just create the json object contain the values from the user input.

Comment: Take a look at [MathJS](http://mathjs.org/index.html) which is a math parser & solver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [math.js](http://mathjs.org) to parse the string input into a function.

```
// If "input" is a variable representing the string input for y
var f = math.eval('f(x) = ' + input');
```

Then compute a range of values for f to pass into chart.js:

```
// If "min" and "max" are values representing the minimum and max  values
var values = [],
var x = min;
var increment = (max - min) / 10000;
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    values[i] = f(x + increment * i);
```